# Mongodb lookup pipeline, comparing a field with an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this sample data:

```
[
  {
    "customers": [
      {"id": 100, "name": "a"},
      {"id": 200, "name": "b"},
      {"id": 300, "name": "c"},
      {"id": 400, "name": "d"}
    ],
    "sales": [
      {
        "sale_id": 9999,
        "persons_related": [
          {"id": 100},
          {"id": 900},
          {"id": 800}
        ]
      },
      {
        "sale_id": 9998,
        "persons_related": [
          {"id": 500},
          {"id": 550},
          {"id": 560}
        ]
      },      
    ]
  }
]
```

It represents two collections, `customers` and `sales`.

Imagine that I am working with the customers collection, I have selected just the customer 100

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
      "customer": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$customers", 0 ]
  }}
}
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "customer": {
      "id": 100,
      "name": "a"
    }
  }
]
```

And I want to find up the sales where this id appears, so I lookup against the same collection, adding this stage to the pipeline:

```
  { $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: { id: "$customer.id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $in: [ "$$id", "$sales.persons_related.id" ] } }
            ]
        }}
      ],
      as: "sales"
    }
  }
```

I need to use this lookup version (the one with `let` and `pipeline`, and not the other one with
`localField`/`foreignField`) because I need to add additional filters in the `match` stage of the pipeline. However, this part:

```
{ $expr: { $in: [ "$$id", "$sales.persons_related.id" ] } }
```

Doesn't work as expected, I have tried with other operators (`$eq`) with same result.

The expected output (using a pipeline in the lookup) should be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "customer": {
      "id": 100,
      "name": "a"
    },
    "sales": [
      {
        "sale_id": 9999,
        "persons_related": [
          {"id": 100},
          {"id": 900},
          {"id": 800}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can you please lend me a hand? You can test on this [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-rMIKIQ9gjn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI mongoplayground provides a multiple collection option, so instead of trying to hack your syntax to simulate it you can just us the dropdown at the top right side to change it.

Your syntax is fine, here is a working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2MzrzQpiKlU) example:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: 100
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sales",
      let: {
        id: "$id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                $expr: {
                  $in: [
                    "$$id",
                    "$persons_related.id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "sales"
    }
  }
])
```

`$lookup` also flattens arrays so you can just use the simpler syntax for it and it simplifies the code:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: 100
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sales",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "persons_related.id",
      as: "sales"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2BoC8qaIZz-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Tom. However, it doesn't work in my "real" example. I have found the problem. In your mongo playground, try to remove the second sale from the sales collection. The $in start to fail. But thanks again for your answer!

Comment: is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JDPlmbEjb3C) what you mean?

Comment: Not exaclty, it's [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5TXTy2MAkPe).  I keep the second sale, but without persons associated. Thanks for your help! I didn't know about the collections on mongo playgrounds, thanks for the tip too 

Comment: Ah, i wasn't aware this field was optional - you can just wrap it with `$ifNull`. like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AUWIWEM5jF3)

Comment: The "simpler" lookup syntax is more resilient

Comment: WOW, super! thank you @Tom, I am quite newbie with mongo and sometimes get lost with the most stupid thing... I know about the simpler lookup, but I need to perform some additional filters in the joined collection, so I prefer to filter on this point than later. Thanks again!!